# I get error in node js in app.js file in app.set

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemon

I don't know why I get an error but if you help i will be very thankful.

Here's My **CODE** of the app.js and important note I have downloaded express and body-parser through the node package manager.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    var today = new Date();
    var option = {
        weekday:"long",
        day:"numeric",
        month:"long"
    };
    var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",option);
res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
res.render('list', {kindOfDay:day});

});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

My **Error**

```
C:\Users\a\Desktop\Todo-List v1\app.js:6
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    ^
TypeError: app.set is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\a\Desktop\Todo-List v1\app.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: `const app = express();` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Loading express module returns a function. So, Please try changing your code like this.
  const app = express();
```

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    var today = new Date();
    var option = {
        weekday:"long",
        day:"numeric",
        month:"long"
    };
    var day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",option);
res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
res.render('list', {kindOfDay:day});

});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const app = express();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
const app = express();
```

In order to generate an [express app](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html), you have to call the express function from you node.